# Can't get text into variable from XML files using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, string, variables

I have been banging my head over this (probably simple) issue and am missing something really basic. Why does this first code display the expected output

```
xmlhttp=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("CenterDataBox").innerHTML= xmlhttp.getElementsByTagName("ShowDay")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

and this second one doesn't? I think this is something really simple I've overlooking.

```
xmlhttp=xmlhttp.responseXML;

var DayOfShow = xmlhttp.getElementsByTagName("ShowDay")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("CenterDataBox").innerHTML= DayofShow;
```

Comment: Use the browser's console! It will tell you the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that your variable **DayOfShow** is not what you're using. You're using DayofShow, without capital '0' letter.

Comment: OK, now that's just embarrassing. Hahahaha Thank you for the quick edit, that fixed it. My eyes must be getting tired.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case-sensitive.

`= DayofShow` should be `= DayOfShow` in example 2.

Comment: Thanks, as I noted above, I think I'm just tired, and looked at it too long. Thank you for your time and effort

Answer (score 0):

You got mispelling of set variable. In example 2 i assume you're getting error var not defined. That is because you set value to Day**O**fShow and below you set inner html to Day**o**fShow. Javascript is case sensitive.

[Here you can read more about JS.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_syntax.asp)